# PHP: How do I convert "2 October, 2012 12:28" to a timestamp using?

Tags: php, date, time

How do I convert "2 October, 2012 12:28" to a comparable timestamp?

Goal is to get a timestamp value on which I can use comparable operators like <, >, = and !=.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you looked at [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)?

Comment: Yeah, I have, but can't seem to figure out what parameters to use.

I would think that '%d %F, %Y %H:%i' would work but it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `DateTime::createFromFormat`

```
$dateTime  = DateTime::createFromFormat("d F, Y g:i", "2 October, 2012 12:28");
var_dump($dateTime->getTimestamp());
```

Output

```
int 1349173680
```

You can also add timezone

```
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat("d F, Y g:i", "2 October, 2012 12:28", new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
var_dump($dateTime->getTimestamp());
```

Output

```
int 1349180880
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it to work with two calls to `strtotime`:

```
$date = strtotime("2 October, 2012");

// Now use the current date to get the time:
$timestamp = strtotime("12:28", $date);
```

You can separate the date segments with `explode`.